# Is there a way to keep the selected row highlighted when the window loses the focus in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, highlighting

When I'm using Excel 2010, and I have a certain row selected, if I then tab away to another window or sheet, the row/cell that's highlighted is no longer visible.  This is really annoying when looking back at the unfocused window.  This there a way to turn this functionality off, so that the row is again highlighted on the unfocused Window?

Comment: there doesn't seem to be any option relating to this.. i'm using Excel 2007 and it has the same behavior.

Comment: @drudge Wow that sucks.  What kind of "feature" did Microsoft add here?

Comment: duplicate of [501560](https://superuser.com/questions/501560/cursor-and-selection-invisible-when-focus-is-lost)

Comment: @leeand00, check the code below, it will help you to fix the issue.

Answer (score -2):

*I would like to suggest use "Workbook Sheet SelectionChange Event" in place of "Workbook_SheetActivate". Because ultimate you need to select a Cell to highlight the Row.*

```
Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

With Target
.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 19
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**How it works:** Select a Cell the Row will be highlighted. Move to other sheet and when you return to the sheet, you find still the Row is highlighted.

To remove fill colour from the Row you can use this code,

```
ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
```